# How to send message to socket client

Tags: java

I would like to add a method to send a String of message to client, it was hard to find a good example on the web. Does it use `write` for sending message to port 8090, do I need to add flush as well?

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    int port = 8090;

    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);


} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html

Comment: 'Hard to find a good example on the web'? Are you kidding? There are millions.

Comment: You are genius, you could actually count millions.

Comment: I was using hyperbole, but anybody can count millions given enough time: you don't have to be a genius. Google gave 'About 3,640,000 results (0.10 seconds)'. That's a lot quicker than waiting around for a reply on a forum. It also gave me the Sun Custom Networking Tutorial, which answers your question completely, as the *first hit.* There is clearly something wrong with your search technique.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Custom Networking](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorial for some working examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the output stream object from the method socket.getOutputStream(). Once you get the output stream you can write using the stream.

Comment: I use to the correct port and address... Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  oos.writeObject("Hi..."); and my xSocket server didn't receive any message